# Highlighting words in the textview that matches from my database values

Tags: android

I have some words in my database.

I want to find all the words whether it is present in the open document..

For Example I am reading my email or any other application than whether it is possible to highlight those words in the mail that matches with my database words.

Using service.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For Example I am reading my email.. than whether it is possible to highlight those words in the mail that matches with my database words.

Only if you are the author of the email app. You have no rights -- or ability -- to modify the UI of other apps.

Comment: Or any other solution for this because babylon application having this facility.

Comment: @JaffarRaza: If you mean "Babylon Translator", it does not "having this facility". It does not highlight text in other apps.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out the string available in your text through any of your desired logic `e.g. string.contains() and/or string.indexOf()` and later you may highlight it as below:

```
TextView lbl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_text_view);
lbl.setText("this is what ever your text is - retrieved from database", 
                                                TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);

Spannable span = (Spannable) lbl.getText();
//e.g. highlighting characters from 0 till 5th index of string
span.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(#BFFF00), 0, 5, 
                                           Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
lbl.setText(span);
```

Comment: I think u cant understand my question ..

Comment: dont you want to highlight words?

Comment: I want to highlight words.. But i want this in any service.. because i write i am reading any email or any other application.

Comment: Sorry, this is just not possible. At first, services don't have any control over Views. Second, you cant perform alterations in behavior of other apps, unless you have access to the code or its your own app